# rm -rf no longer deletes folder in cron job

Tags: bash, linux-mint, cron, btrfs, rm

I wrote a program that writes a large number of small files to a temporary directory, then, via a call from within the program, deletes the temporary directory.  This program is called via a user-level cron job and the temporary directory and all files contained within are of standard permissions with me as the owner.  For over a year, this has worked on my system (Linux Mint 19.3), until I discovered that recently the deletion process, which is a program-called shell command to `rm -rf dir` was no longer deleting the directory and its contents.  I tried tacking on an additional `rm -rf dir` to the end of the cron job, but strangely this too failed.  There are too many temporary files in the folder to delete inside the directory via `rm *`.  The files are located on a second drive to my computer, different from root, which is formatted to BTRFS.  I use Bash for the shell.

When I first noticed this issue, I tried to delete the folder manually with the same rm command, and it strangely errored out, mentioning it couldn't find the shell commands (which made no sense).  Opening another shell instance and performing the exact same command went through without error.  I note this as perhaps it might relate to the issue at hand.  I haven't had this problem since, and used timeshift to restore the operating system thinking there might have been disk corruption or a kernel bug.  However, even after all these measures, the problem still remains.

This issue is very odd, as I can manually delete the folder with `rm`, but cannot do it in the cron job like it was doing before, either through the commands called by the program I am running, or even through an explicit command after the program runs to delete the temporary folder.

Does anyone have an idea what may have caused this cron-job to stop deleting the folder?

Comment: Does the program use a fixed location for the temporary directory? How often does the job run? How long does it take? What if one instance tries to remove the directory when another instance keeps creating files in it? Can you make each instance use unique directory (something like `mktemp -d`)?

Comment: What are the ownership perms of thr parent directory? Is anything holding the directory open?  I wonder if using find and/or xargs to delete the files would work?

Comment: Have you captured error output from the script? That'll often give an indication of what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm redirecting the error from rm to a file today so I can show it when I capture it.  The program uses the same "name" for the temporary directory, and runs daily.  It deletes, then remakes the now-empty folder with mkdir.  There shouldn't be a conflict with writing/deleting the folder, as rm is always called after the writing part of the program is done.  I'll check for permissions later today as well, but it should be the linux mint default, 644.

Comment: Does the same error occur if you use the full path to `rm`, e.g., `/usr/bin/rm -rf dir`?

Comment: It appears the files inside the folder have 664 permission and the folder has 775 permission, so permissions should not be a problem.  I tried to capture the message, but it appears the job didn't write stdout to a file.  I will try to have it echo something to a file to see what is happening.  I will also try to call rm, which on my system is in /bin/mr.  I have had problems in the past where cron can't run jobs unless you type cd to the folder you have the program in, so I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved the problem, but I have no understanding why or what caused it.  In the cron job, I was calling subsequent commands with **&&** rather than **;**.  Because the shell commands in the program failed, the subsequent commands were never called.  After commenting out the failing commands and recompiling, the tacked-on **rm** works.

I was using C++17 with a call to **system()** and this was causing the failure, if this helps anyone.